# Не сохраняется массив

Tags: android, массивы, list, arraylist

Сделал перебор ровно по этому уроку (http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/), но массив UsersBackUp все равно равен нулю, т.е. при инициализации он не заполняется.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<UserDetails> Users = null;
    private ArrayList<UserDetails> UsersBackUp;

    public ListViewAdapter(List<UserDetails> Users, Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        this.Users = Users;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.UsersBackUp = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
        this.UsersBackUp.addAll(Users);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;
        TextView Online;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return Users.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.Name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.Online = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.Name.setText(Users.get(i).getUsername());

        if (Users.get(i).getOnline())
        {
            holder.Online.setText("Онлайн");
        }
        else
        {
            holder.Online.setText("Оффлайн");
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        Users.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0)
        {
            Users.addAll(UsersBackUp);
            Log.d("myLog null ", UsersBackUp.size() + " size");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("myLog ", " yes");
            for (UserDetails wp : UsersBackUp)
            {
                if (wp.getUsername().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    Log.d("myLog ", wp.getUsername() + " username");
                    Users.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Структура

```
public class UserDetails {
    private String Username;
    private String Token;
    private String Id;
    private Boolean Online;

    public UserDetails(String Username, String Token, String Id, String Online)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Token = Token;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Online = Boolean.valueOf(Online);
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return this.Username;
    }

    public String getToken()
    {
        return this.Token;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public Boolean getOnline()
    {
        return this.Online;
    }
}
```

Comment: нужен код, где вызывается new ListViewAdapter(Users, context)  и заполняется сам исходный список Users. Возможно, просто одно выполняется раньше другого.

Comment: Действительно помогло, спасибо :)